# What to do with posts with a proper answer that the user does not mark as the answer?

Tags: discussion, moderators, unanswered-questions

There are a many questions that has been answered, and many of them has not been marked as "the" answer. Seems like a lot of users are just asking but does not bother to mark them.

It can become a bit annoying for users who answers a lot, since they do not get their points, and the posts remains as unanswered.

Can for example admins mark them?

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange considers questions as answered when they have an answer with an upvote. So if you feel that the answer is a [good one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) just upvote it and the question is counted as answered.

Furthermore a user can [accept an answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly.  It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for him or her personally, …

So accepting an answer is a personal thing to a user. I don't think that an administrator should make this choice.

Comment: I see, and i agree with you.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Agreed — this is a common misconception on the SE network. Instead of looking for the green check, look for questions with lots of answers!